# Spring Boot Java Request GET Request Mapping URL problems

Tags: spring-boot, jira-rest-java-api

How to turn this 【http://myurl.com/test/api/v1/data/?:getlicense=1234】

to this way 【http://myurl.com/test/api/v1/data/:getlicense/1234】

The code below using postman GET http://myurl.com/test/api/v1/data/?:getlicense=1234 will return result success.

Below is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/data/" ,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,headers="Accept=*/*",method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public Map ReturnData(@RequestParam(":getlicense") String getdata) {
        Map returns = new HashMap();
          try {
                 queryData qD= new queryData ();
                 qD.setData(getdata);
                 returns = result.getdataList(qD);
              } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
              }
           return returns;
    }
```

please  help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your RequestParam to a PathVariable

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/data/licenses/{id}")
public Map returnData(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {

    Map returns = new HashMap();
    try {
        queryData qD= new queryData ();
        qD.setData(id);
        returns = result.getdataList(qD);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below solution

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/data/licenses/{id}" ,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,headers="Accept=*/*",method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public Map ReturnData(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
        Map returns = new HashMap();
          try {
                 queryData qD= new queryData ();
                 qD.setData(id);
                 returns = result.getdataList(qD);
              } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
              }
           return returns;
    }
```

Comment: http://myurl.com/test/api/v1/data/:getlicense/1234 <-- i need it this way
i have try the way you suggest is it postman problem? is still 404

Comment: do u want ':getlicense' or 'getlicense' ? 'colon' (:) might not be supported

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/data/:licenses/{id}" try this in requestmapping. might work !